# Display data from firestore based on document id

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ngfor

I created an Angular 6 with Ionic 4 app and I am having a little trouble returning specific data from the Google Cloud Firestore database. I created "cards" that display multiple stats that I am grabbing from the Firestore.
[Here is an example](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#card-image) of how my cards are designed. What I want to accomplish is that instead of typing in the titles of the cards manually, I want to grab them all from the database and display on each of the cards based on the document ID. For example, let's say I have document IDs from 1-10 with information in them like "name, title, song". Now for each title, I want to grab it from the database like this

```
<div *ngFor="let note of cards | async">
  <h1>{{note.title}}</h1>
</div>
```

but Instead of `note.title` I want to do something like this `note.title[1]` where 1 is my first document ID etc etc. Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Ionic Blank</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

    <ion-card>

        <img src="../../../assets/images/pavilion.jpg" />

        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
                <div *ngFor="let note of cards | async">

                    <h1>{{note.title}}</h1>

                </div>
            </ion-card-title>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore\
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                commodo consequat.
            </p>
        </ion-card-content>

        <ion-row no-padding>
            <ion-col>
                <button ion-button clear small icon-start class="dangerColor">
                    <ion-icon name='star'></ion-icon>
                    Favorite
                </button>
            </ion-col>

            <ion-col text-center>
                <button ion-button clear small icon-start class="dangerColor">
                    <ion-icon name='share-alt'></ion-icon>
                    Share
                </button>
            </ion-col>

            <ion-col text-right>
                <button ion-button clear small icon-start class="dangerColor" routerLink="/maps">
                    <ion-icon name='arrow-dropright'></ion-icon>
                    More
                </button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

    </ion-card>

    <!--Second Card-->
    <ion-card>

        <img src="../../../assets/images/statehouse2011.jpg" />

        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
                <div *ngFor="let note of cards | async">
                   <h1>{{note.title}}</h1>
                </div>
            </ion-card-title>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore\
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
                commodo consequat.
            </p>
        </ion-card-content>

        <ion-row no-padding>
            <ion-col>
                <button ion-button clear small icon-start class="dangerColor">
                    <ion-icon name='star'></ion-icon>
                    Favorite
                </button>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col text-center>
                <button ion-button clear small icon-start class="dangerColor">
                    <ion-icon name='share-alt'></ion-icon>
                    Share
                </button>
            </ion-col>

            <ion-col text-right>
                <button ion-button clear small icon-start class="dangerColor">
                    <ion-icon name='arrow-dropright'></ion-icon>
                    More
                </button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

    </ion-card>

</ion-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface Note {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    id: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

    cardsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Note>;
    cards: Observable<Note[]>;

    constructor(
        private afs: AngularFirestore
    ) {
        this.cardsCollection = this.afs.collection('cards')
        this.cards = this.cardsCollection.valueChanges()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to work with the document ID's, you have two options:

#### 1. Use the method [snapshotChanges()](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges)

- Like its written in the AngularFire documentation: 
  **"Why would you use it? - When you need a list of data but also want to keep around metadata"** (The id for example)

#### 2. Add the document ID manually while creating the documents

or

#### 3. If you just want to enumerate

- You could use the index of ngFor:

`<div *ngFor="let note of cards | async; let i = index">
        <h1>{{ i }} {{ note.title }}</h1>
    </div>`